# iphone sdk - detect user or light input

Tags: iphone

I'm writing a little application and have fallen at the first hurdle nearly! I wanted to have an action happen when the light level dropped below a certain threshold. I've since found out you cannot access the light meter in the SDK, so I am thinking of another way of doing it.

(I assume I am correct in saying you cannot detect the light level?? - in my app, I ideally wanted to call an event when it goes dark...)

Could I somehow call an event ANY other way when the light level drops??

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use IOKit (the IOHID stuff) to detect Ambient Light Sensor events. There's no AppStore-compatible way to do it.